# Оператор сравнения == и конструкция if

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с таким нюансом, что `if` и конструкция `var== false/true` выдают разные результаты. Пожалуй, код продемонстрирует лучше слов:

```
if ({} && []) {
    console.log(({} && []) == true); // сработает и выведет false
}
```

То есть выражение `{} && []` в конструкции `if` ведёт себя как `true`. Но при явном применении оператора сравнения говорит, что это не так. И я нигде не могу найти объяснения, которое бы меня удовлетворило. Другой показательный пример:

```
var c = new Boolean(false);
if(c) {// == true - не сработает
    console.log("8))))");
    console.log(c==false);
}
```

На всех ресурсах, что я нашел, только вскользь в пяти словах упоминается о разном поведении, но никакого экскурса в причины.

Единственная нить с одного из них, за которую я зацепился - это valueof. Якобы при `==` происходит численное сравнение, а не логическое, а за преобразование самого объекта в число отвечает именно `valueOf`. Но в описании самого `valueOf` я не нашел никакой четкой информации, кроме как той, что если он не переопределен, то наследуется от `Object` - но какая его реализация у `Object`? Какие правила? Почему, например, `[2] == false`, как `[]`, а `[1] == true`?

Наткнулся так же на такую таблицу
https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/
Она хоть и хороша, но похоже, составлена методом тыка и не даёт, ответа, что, почему и откуда берутся именно эти значения.

Comment: Оно ведёт себя не как true, а как *truthy* значение, которое считается истинным в условиях. Массив считается истинным, но при этом он совершенно не обязан быть равным true

Comment: Вообще, если я правильно помню, любой непримитивный объект считается истинным, поэтому `new Boolean(false)` тоже считается истинным, в то время как `false` это примитив, который истинным уже не считается

Comment: @andreymal , с thruthy более менее понятно. Мне как-то собой разумеющееся, что {} будет вести себя как true, тк это объект (и в интернете про такое поведение в основном). У меня больше вызывает вопрос, почему он может быть не равен примитивному типу `true`?

Comment: А с `==` всё сложно, [вот тут есть таблица приведений типов](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using). Если я правильно понимаю, массив приводится сперва к строке, а потом к числу, поэтому `[]==false` (пустой массив→пустая строка→0==false) и `[0]==false` по той же логике (массив→"0"→0), но при этом `[1]==true` (true приводится к числу 1, false к числу 0)

Comment: Не согласен, что это дубликат, разве что по названию. По ссылке речь о примитивных типах, у меня же примеры с объектами, и ответы той ветки не покрывают, как, например `[]` или даже `[2]` приводится к `false`, (а `[1]` почему-то `true`)

Comment: @Александр, в ответе приведен алгоритм, что к чему приводится в какой момент, а так же что именно происходит с условием в `if`

Answer (score 0):

Логический оператор && возвращает правое значение, если левое истина, то есть оператор if некорректно сравнивать с (), которое возвращает полученный результат, в данном случае ({} && []) вернет пустой массив объект и сравнивать его с истиной тоже некорректно. Оператор if преобразует выражение к логическому типу и если выражение равно 0, пустой строке "", null, undefined и NaN, то результат становится false, иначе истина.

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение по `&&`, но оператор `&&` тут не играет существенной роли. Можно взять отдельно `[]` и `{}` или даже `[2,4]` и `{a:5}`, ситуация не поменяется. С if они все вернут true, а с оператором == вернут false

Comment: Потому что оператор if преобразует выражение к логическому типу, а оператор == просто сравнивает. Оператор if работает примерно вот так, на примере пустого объекта массива []: ([] !== 0 && [] !== "" && [] !== null && [] !== undefined && [] !== NaN)

Comment: да с `if` все ясно. Как сравнение-то работает? Например, почему `[1]==true`, а `[2]==false`. Почему `{a:4}==false`?

Comment: потому что такое == сравнение использует преобразование к числовому значению аналогично Number([1]) даст 1, и Number(true) даст 1, поэтому 1==1, в то время как Number([2]) даст 2, и Number(false) даст 0, получается не равенство 2!=0. Поэтому нужно в таких случаях использовать строгое сравнение без преобразования типов === в число, для корректного сравнения.

Comment: вот подобное объяснение я находил, но остаётся вопрос: неравенство `2!=0` выдаст `false`, почему тогда `2==false`?

Comment: неравенство 2!=0 выдает true, потому что 2 не равно 0, - "все верно". А равенство 2==false выдает false, потому что 2 не равно 0, - "не верно".

Comment: странно, по такой логике `1!=0`, значит должно быть `1==false`, но это не так

Comment: Не понимаю о чем это. в 1 условии) 1 не равен 0 - результат истина, 2 условие) 1 равен 0 - результат ложь. Вполне логично

Comment: Почитал про The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm

в es5.1, там многие ответы есть в принципе. Вы, видимо, правы насчёт Number([]). А преобразование, 2==false и 1==true исходит из преобразования Number(bool), но все равно не до конца понимаю, почему 2== false...

Comment: ...но все равно не до конца понимаю, почему 2== false... , потому что идет сравнение числа 2 и 0, это два разных числа, поэтому результат ложь, если сравнить 1 == true будет результат истина, потому что будет сравнение 1 и 1, если сравнить 2 == true, то результат будет ложь, потому что сравниваются числа 2 и 1, они не одинаковые.

Comment: А сравнение с помощью == любого объекта с истиной или ложью, в любом случае выдаст результат ложь, потому что Number({}) вернет абстрактное значение NaN, которое является так сказать изначальным значением, и сравнение этого значения с любым числом, выдаст результат ложь. Тоесть NaN это и не 0 и не 1, это нечто другое.

Comment: @Max, на счет _сравнение с помощью == любого объекта с истиной или ложью, в любом случае выдаст результат ложь_:  https://jsfiddle.net/5mxne92w/

Comment: @Max , в принципе так, спасибо. Я готов принять ваш ответ, если вы перенесете туда алгоритм `==false/true` сравнений, который описали в комментариях, поскольку вопрос был о работе оператора сравнения с булевым значением

Comment: @Grundy мне кажется, про объекты - не совсем корректное утверждение, ведь `[1]` - тоже объект, но он будет `==true`

Comment: @Александр, по ссылке на fiddle в моем комментарии можно увидеть что и для литерала объекта это утверждение не верно